# JQuery dynamic iFrame function

Tags: jquery, iframe

I've created a function called loadFrame with an argument called id. When this function is called, jQuery iframe is created and it loads a url with the id argument in the string. Here is the code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function loadFrame(id){
    $('body').append('<iframe src="loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary" name="frame1" id="frame1" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>');
}

</script>

<span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>
```

Problem that I am facing is that every time i click to load an iFrame, it keeps creating a new instance of the iFrame. I want there to only be one instance of the iFrame at all times.

Is there a way to have like a close icon on the top right of the iFrame so that I can unload the iframe completely?

Thanks

Got it working using the suggestions below. Here is the working code:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function loadFrame(id){
    $('#iframecontent').html('<div id="iframe_'+id+'" style="position:relative;width:400px;"><button onclick="unloadFrame(\''+id+'\')" data-tar="'+id+'">Close</button><iframe src="loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary" name="frame" id="frame" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>');
}

function unloadFrame(id){
    var iframeid = "#iframe_"+id;
    $(iframeid).remove();
}    

</script>

<span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>

<div id="iframecontent"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        function loadFrame(id){

            $('iframe').remove();
            $('body').append('<iframe src="loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary" name="frame1" id="frame1" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>');
        }

        </script>

        <span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
        <span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
        <span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>
```

or this:

```
function loadFrame(id){


    $('#frame1').attr('src','loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary');
}

</script>

<span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>

<iframe src="" name="frame1" id="frame1" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Because everytime your trying to append the content,Instead use `html` function to insert the document at particular instance.

```
function loadFrame(id){
$('#iframecontent').html('<iframe src="loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary"
name="frame1" id="frame1" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;">
</iframe>');
}
```

**Html:**

```
<span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>
<div id="iframecontent"></div>
```

Comment: Works great for the single instance. So used this combined with the example by rynhe. I've updated my code above to show the latest working code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**demo :**  http://fiddle.jshell.net/njPQP/1/

```
<span onclick="loadFrame(1);">Summary for User 1</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(2);">Summary for User 2</span>
<span onclick="loadFrame(3);">Summary for User 3</span>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

function loadFrame(id){
    var iframeid = "#iframe_"+id;    
    if($(iframeid).length < 1)
    var append_data = '<div id="iframe_'+id+'" style="position:relative;width:400px;"><button onclick="unloadFrame(\''+id+'\')" data-tar="'+id+'">Close</button><iframe src="loadFrame.php?id=' + id + '&cmd=summary" name="frame" id="frame" style="border:none; width:400px;height:200px;overflow:hidden;"></iframe></div>';
     $('body').append(append_data);
}

function unloadFrame(id){
    var iframeid = "#iframe_"+id;
    $(iframeid).remove();
}    

</script>
```

Comment: Used this in combination with Joke_Sense10 example.